# Is the spectral radius of a Hermitian matrix a non-decreasing function of the magnitude of its entries?

Tags: matrices

I strongly suspect the answer is yes. By the [min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem), the largest eigenvalue of a hermitian matrix $M$ is
$$
\lambda_{max}=\text{max} \left( \frac{x^*Mx}{x^*x} \right)
$$
This is also its spectral radius. It seems intuitively that $\lambda_{max}$ could not decrease if some entries of $M$ increased in magnitude (in such a way that $M$ remains hermitian of course), but I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true even for positive-definite real matrices. If $\lambda$ is the leading eigenvalue with eigenvector $v$ (and assuming that this eigenvalue is simple) then the derivative of $\lambda$ with respect to the $(i,j)$th entry of $M$ is given by
$$v^T(e_{i} \otimes e_{j}) v = v_iv_j.$$

Of course to keep $M$ symmetric you need to vary both the $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$th entry and will get a factor of $2$, but in any case generally these derivative will not all have the correct sign. As a concrete example consider
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}3 & -1 & 1\\-1 & 2 & 1\\1 & 1 & 2\end{array}\right].$$
Increasing the $(2,3)$ and $(3,2)$ entries decreases the spectral radius.

One case where your property *will* hold is if the matrix has all positive entries, since the leading eigenvector will have all positive entries by the Perron–Frobenius theorem.